# Concat database tables 1 field multiple records string in one row

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I have a tables and records like :

```
EmployeeName
------------
Ram
Laxman
Bharat
Shatrugn
```

where i want to output to concat all values in one row in a single query:

I want result like:

```
Ram,Laxman,bharat,shatrugn
```

Concat string with ,(comma) in singlee line..
but i don't know that how to concat in android using cursor...

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/JoinanarrayofStringstogether.htm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
select Group_Concat(EmployeeName)
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2b1d3/1)

If you had multiple fields that you want to return, then you would use a `GROUP BY` with the query, similar to this:

```
select id, Group_Concat(EmployeeName)
from table1
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/29a51/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
     String values;
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

               values=values + cursor.getString(0)+",";

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

remove last comma

```
if (values.length() > 0)
 {
    values= values.substring(0,values.length() - 1);    
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code i used...hope it helps you.

```
 private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
 Cursor cursor;
 String S="";
 String myPath2 = yourDBpath + yourDBNAME;
 try{
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath2, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
 String sql="your query";
 cursor=myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(cursor != null)
{
   while(cursor.moveToNext())
   {
    S=S.append(cursor.getString(0));
    }
}
  } 
}catch(Exception e){

        }finally{
        myDataBase.close();
        }
```

Final result will be there in String S.